# Simple html page using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a simple HTML page using the Twitter Bootstrap.

But the navbar and links are rendered as normal HTML on the browser.

I have referred to multiple sites but the same steps are given everywhere. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 

<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "css/bootstrap.css"  type="text/css">

<title> Bootstrap example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
 <div class ="container">

 <h1><a href="#">Bootstrap Site</a></h1>
 <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <link rel ”stylesheet” href ”css/bootstrap.css”  type=”text/css”> < ...

Comment: Do you see the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js loading properly?? When you press f12 ?

Comment: Add script reference proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect quotations (`”` instead of `"` or `'`) and missing a few equals (`=`) signs. Change:

```
<meta charset=”utf-8”> 
<link rel ”stylesheet” href ”css/bootstrap.css”  type=”text/css”>
...
<script src ”js/bootstrap.js”></script>
```

To:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
...
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien that wouldn't tell the user what or where the problem is.

Comment: Just leave a comment, else crap will get on accumulating :)

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly. But correcting the typos wouldnt make any difference.

Comment: @Athashri in that case your Bootstrap-related files are probably not in the directories you're specifying. Open your browser's console and see if it is displaying any errors about files not being found.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Somehow my js and css files were empty :/ . Now working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Athashri no worries, please mark the answer which has helped you the most as accepted when you get the chance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not including bootstrap (probably wrong copy/paste from somewhere).

change

```
<link rel ”stylesheet” href ”css/bootstrap.css”  type=”text/css”>
<script src ”js/bootstrap.js”></script>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"></link>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```